# How do you add a web reference through a proxy/firewall?

Tags: .net, proxy, web-reference

I'm behind a firewall at work at the moment and I was testing something that I had deployed to my website, and the work proxy seems to be blocking it somewhat.

Basically I am getting a message of:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

I've got it down to my proxy interferring, but I can't see any advanced settings or anything I can set up to go through my proxy to get to my service.

I did a quick google for it, but no joy.

Anyone found a quick way to get around it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit, I forgot to write this part in the answer: You may need to add the web reference url to the safe list for your proxy.  I am not sure what proxy you are using or if you have control of it, but this should solve your problem.  If you don't have access to change the proxy, then I put a quick work around right below.

Here's a quick work around, just use the browser to navigate to the WSDL.  Grab the xml and save it as a .wsdl file on your computer you would like to generate the client on.  Then use the [wsdl.exe](http://shrinkster.com/11sv) to generate the client pointing it to the path you saved the wsdl file.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to go to your application's web config or app config and add the following under the  element:

```
<system.net> 
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="false">
       <proxy usesystemdefault="true" proxyaddress="10.0.0.1" port="80" bypassonlocal="true" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

You can then add the web reference in the normal way.