# Web reference doesn't want to add in project

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm trying to add new web reference in my project. When I enter url in window below it shows web service description (all methods with descrption). But in the right panel there is message "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" and I can't add my web-service.
I tried to add some other services and program has added them. So it seems like I have a problem with wsdl. What should be in wsdl for Visual Studio?

Also I tested this web-service in soapUI and everything works fine.

Comment: Have you restarted Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes. Visual Studio doesn't even tell what's wrong.

Comment: Try adding a service reference.

Comment: I'm click "Add web reference". How can I add a service reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Try this solution](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2012/01/19/operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of.aspx), add the following to your `web.config`

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2000" />
 </appSettings>
```

Comment: I have a Console Application. Where this web.config is?
 I've found the same problem discussion [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1331361.aspx/1)
But I don't understand why then I see web-service description with methods?

Comment: Oops.. my bad. I should add web-service URL to the safe list for my proxy. The solution is [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984/how-do-you-add-a-web-reference-through-a-proxy-firewall).

Sorry )

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue however I came to know that the company proxy was not allowing to connect to external web-service.